# Как правильнее добавлять события addEventListener на кнопки

Tags: javascript, события

```
//Первый вариант, тут проверка наличия кнопок - некоторые страницы отличаются набором кнопок.  
const menu_btn = document.querySelector('.menu_btn');
if (menu_btn) menu_btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   document.querySelector('.menu').classList.toggle('open');
});
const cart_btn = document.querySelector('.cart_btn');
if (cart_btn) cart_btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   document.querySelector('.cart').classList.toggle('open');
});  

//Второй вариант
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
   if(e.target){
      if(e.target.classList.contains('menu_btn')){
         document.querySelector('.menu').classList.toggle('open');
      }
      if(e.target.classList.contains('cart_btn')){
         document.querySelector('.cart').classList.toggle('open');
      }
   }
});
```

Второй вариант при нескольких кнопках будет ощутимо короче плюс не создаются лишние переменные.
И все-таки как правильнее?
**UPD.** Забыл уточнить: кнопки добавляются на страницу скриптом, изначально на странице отсутствуют.

Comment: Взять модуль delegated-events и не возиться с этими портянками?)

Comment: Что за модуль? У меня страница ванильная, весь js 12кБ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.matches('.общий-класс-всех-подобных-кнопок'))
    return; 
  let tglEl = target.dataset.toggleEl; 
  try {
    tglEl = document.querySelector(target.dataset.toggleEl); 
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(`Некорректный селектор '${tglEl}'\n${target.outerHTML}`); 
  }
  if (tglEl) 
    tglEl.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

MDN: [Использование data-атрибутов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Answer (score 1):

Если функции однотипные и не хочется использовать сторонние решения,
 можно сделать что-то наподобие:
(Т.е. определить функцию с минимальным количеством параметров и вызвать ее только с ними, в примере это две query).

```
var fnAddEl = function(firstq, secondq) {
    var el = document.querySelector(firstq);
    if (el) {
        el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            document.querySelector (secondq).classList.toggle('open');
        });
    }
};
fnAddEl('.menu_btn', '.menu');
fnAddEl('.cart_btn', '.cart');
```

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, нюанс в динамичном добавлении кнопок, изначально их нет на странице.

Comment: Вероятно тогда зависит от того как добавляются кнопки. В рамках данного варианта, можно функцию объявить один раз, и вызывать ее после добавления кнопки (или в сам код добавляющий кнопку встроить вызов, тогда если есть элемент кнопки можно без первого firstq делать).